# Get id where values are true with jq

Tags: json, bash, select, jq

I am trying to loop through each of the objects in the json file and get the `id` name for where `trunk` is `true`. Right now I am only getting the `id` for each of the objects.

json file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "bmw",
    "color": "blue",
    "trunk": true,
    "seat": false
  },
  {
    "id": "merceredes",
    "color": "blue",
    "trunk": false,
    "seat": false
  }

]
```

bash script:

```
/bin/bash
for id in `jq -r -c .[] file.json`; do
  echo $id | jq -r .id
done
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven’t specified the precise form of output you want, but the following illustrates one approach to the problem:

```
jq '.[] | select(.trunk == true) | .id' file.json
```

If .trunk is boolean, you could simplify the `select` parameter to `.trunk`.

Comment: Thanks @peak for your reply. In my echo line in the `for-loop` I have the following: `echo $id | jq .[] | select(.trunk == true) | .id` and I get this error: `./config.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./config.sh: line 4: `  echo $id | jq .[] | select(.trunk == true) | .id'
`

Comment: After adding single qoutes after `jq` and after `.id` I am recieving: `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "trunk"`